# How to convert dictionary lists of different lengths into excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list, dictionary

When I write some crawler code, I save the final data in a dictionary list, but different dictionaries, their keys have some inconsistencies, but the total number of keys is certain, I am confused how to put them according to the dictionary keys , organize and generate an excel table, those properties that are not used can be replaced by NAN.

I used pycharm to write this code and I thought it may use pandas to solve, but I still had no idea about how to do it.

This is a simple pattern:

```
a = {'m': 1, 'n': 2}
b = {'m': 3, 'n': 4, 'p': 5}
c = {'m': 6, 'n': 7, 'o': 8, 'p': 9}
d = [a, b, c]
```

The result I want to likes this:

```
        m   n   o   p
   0    1   2   NAN NAN
   1    3   4   NAN 5
   2    6   7   8   9
```

Comment: Just adding a bunch of tags is not the way to ask a question, what software/language is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using a [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> print(df)
   m  n    o    p
0  1  2  NaN  NaN
1  3  4  NaN  5.0
2  6  7  8.0  9.0
```

You can then store it directly into an excel file using the [df.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) method, or even copy it into your clipboard using `df.to_clipboard()`:

```py
>>> df.to_excel('path/to/your.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's a really helpful method for me.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it was useful! If so, I'll appreciate if you can mark the answer as accepted ;-)

Comment: I‘m so sorry I mark the answer as accepted so late. Because I haven't viewed stackoverflow these days!  Thanks a lot again!